# Movie like Body Snatchers - with bus and Cielito Lindo

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching this film (dubbed in Italian) in the late 90s, during a bus trip with university friends. I don't remember if it was on VHS or DVD, but VHS is more probable.

It wasn't one of the [various remakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Body_Snatchers_films) of *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*, but the idea was similar: aliens are secretly replacing humans, someone finds out and must stop them. Water tanks were involved: storage for the original human bodies? (But IIRC they were parallelepipedal, [not the usual cylinders](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24623/the-cliche-science-fiction-glass-tube-filled-with-liquid-and-a-person-floating-i)).

I remember this movie as having a mix of serious and humorous elements... but maybe my memory is playing tricks to me, and the only "funny" things were low-budget effects and two curious coincidences:

- There was a scene on a bus, and we *were* on a bus
- *Cielito Lindo* was in the soundtrack, and we loved that song at that time (because reasons)

I'm pretty sure that *Cielito Lindo* and the bus were in the same scene, near the end (a bus in Mexico? a bus from USA *to* Mexico?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been years but...
Ok I was on YouTube and found this movie series and it made me remember this question because of cielito lindo song and the bus. I think I finally found the answer by accident.
The Invaders 1995 Was going to be a series based in a series of the 60s with the same story abd name if not mistaken.
YT link

Time  1:13:30 has the scene with the bus and cielito lindo
Around 1:20:00 has the scene with the water tanks and the bodies in them or the process.
It is low budget and effects do look bad.

Comment: Wow.  Cielito Lindo is in many movies, but this one I didn't find.  Great find.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks! Strange I did not remember Scott Bakula. And I was wrong about "Cielito Lindo and the bus were in the same scene, near the end". They are together, but NOT near the end. But Cielito Lindo plays also during end credits (just after the protagonist goes away by car at 02:48:36, that tricked my memory). I read that the Home Video version is slightly shorter and has different editing. The Italian dub in VHS does indeed exist, foreign-subtitled "Gli invasori sono tra noi" (Invaders are among us), also available on Amazon Prime Video.

Comment: Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 3):

The Faculty, 1998
To the students at Harrington High, the principal and her posse of teachers have always been a little odd, but lately they've been behaving positively alien. Controlled by otherworldly parasites, the faculty try to infect students one by one. Cheerleader Delilah (Jordana Brewster), football player Stan (Shawn Hatosy), drug dealer Zeke (Josh Hartnett) and new girl Marybeth (Laura Harris) team up with some of their other classmates to fight back against the invaders.
The aliens need water,  and there is a scene with a school bus.

Comment: Upvoted for the tentative, but I've seen The Faculty (I also have it in DVD) and it's not the one I'm referring to. I remember a ragged but otherwise "normal" bus, not a school bus.